What would you do to mount a TV above this fireplace?
I want to mount my tv above this fireplace. does anyone have any ideas? Do I need a hearth with a gas fireplace? How low could I mount television? Do I need mantle? thanks.

Do you plan to actually use the fireplace to burn anything?

General advice is that above a fireplace is not a good place for a TV. If it's a real fireplace, the heat and smoke will be bad for the set. Even if it's a fake fireplace, looking up at the screen is uncomfortable for most people in most chairs; review the manufacturer's suggestions. If you must mount it high, I hope you have reclining chairs, and you should probably consider a mount that lets you tilt it forward. Details of mounting will depend on the construction of the wall, and have been addressed in answers to past questions.

@keshlam - over fireplace TVs are the worst idea ever.   It is a last gasp thing were you have no where else.   Since it can be installed in the corner... I would do that first.

I would not do anything

How big is the TV and how wide is the fireplace?

I'd run the fire place and measure the temperature above it where the tv will live.  Does it feel crazy hot?  You can probably get a mount that has a swing away feature that allow you to move the tv when you want to run the fireplace.

@FreshCodemonger or perhaps a motorized ceiling mount that could raise the TV out of the hottest area.  Or a tracked mount where the TV could be slid to the side out of the way when the fireplace is in use.

You have a number of questions but give us very little information.  Is the fireplace wood or gas burning?  What is the construction of the wall the fireplace is on?  How big is the TV you plan to mount?  How often will you be using the fireplace?  An easy answer would be to find studs and screw the TV mount into studs. However this may  get you a wall mounted Tv but also be the death of the TV in short order.

@Moore: Unfortunately, home decor magazines seem determined to promote this bad idea. I can see why it seems appealing; it makes the same wall the focus whether you are looking at the fire or at the screen and thus may simplify room layout. But the people who design rooms for magazines don't have to live in them.

I have a different view than others.  I have always mounted our TVs above the fireplace.

Contrary to other opinions, we have never found the TV to be too high.  In fact it is a better height for your neck.  This assumes that the TV is a suitable distance from the sofa/chairs (say about 2m).

It also does not necessarily get that hot.

Put a mantle piece to be safe.  This will deflect some heat and the odd smoke if the fireplace is going to generate some smoke.
You can install a heat deflector under the mantle if its timber.  This is basically a flat piece of metal (we anodized it black to look nice), on little stands, hanging under the mantle.  The local authorities here insist on it for a wooden mantle anyway.
You can measure the temperature where the TV is going to be.  Above 50°C is starting to get high for the electronics.  Most stuff is rated for 55, some is rated for 75.  That is  for the components to stay within normal operational range.




If however, its is going to be an open fireplace and you are going to burn wood, than the smoke is of concern.  Apart from the soot getting deposited inside the TV, the smoke can be corrosive, specially if the wood is wet or green or you accidentally toss in treated timber.
